# The translation of "What would Caesar do?" in classical Latin

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation

The translation of "What would Caesar do?" in classical Latin.

I've researched a lot and I've not found any evidence of what this phrase would be in classical Latin.
Any guest?
I'm trying to replicate the Marcus Aurelius stoic phrase about Zeno "What would Zeno do?", but using Caesar instead.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I assume you mean the Roman name (and later title) *Caesar* instead of *Cesar*, so I took the liberty of supplying an *a* in the first syllable. Feel free to edit your question to add any further details.

Comment: That phrase is the product of some American pop philosopher, so I'm not sure why translating it into Latin is something you'd want to do. (Marcus Aurelius himself wrote in Greek, FWIW.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want something analogous to another phrase, you can edit your question to provide the original Latin one to be varied.
Adapting a single word would be easy.

Without any context, a decent translation would be: ***Quid faceret Caesar?***
The imperfect conjunctive is used for conditions that you know never to be realized, and that indeed seems to be the case: Caesar is not here, but if he were, what would he do?